# Statistics availability in MariaDB

Tags: statistics, mariadb

I would like to try out "engine-independent" statistics in MariaDB due to the stated benefits over storage-engine stats.
I have therefore set use_stat_tables=preferably in /etc/mysql/my.cnf and reloaded service.

After reconnecting as the user and performing

> ANALYZE TABLE tbl PERSISTENT FOR ALL;

The table_stats table is populated as expected;

I queried the system variable:

> show variables like 'use_stat_tables';

and the value is still set to "NEVER". I was expecting PREFERABLY.
Anybody suggest why the system variable has not changed?

Comment: Are you able to set the value on the MySQL console?

Comment: I've tried as follows:

    `MariaDB [pktest]> set global use_stat_tables='preferably';  
     Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

    MariaDB [pktest]> show variables like 'use_stat_tables';
    +-----------------+-------+
    | Variable_name   | Value |
    +-----------------+-------+
    | use_stat_tables | NEVER | 
    +-----------------+-------+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)`

Comment: Your MariaDb version is above 10.0.1, right?

Comment: yes

$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.16-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

Answer (score 0):

The user with which I had issued the command

```
set global use_stat_tables='prefetably';
```

did not have the correct permissions.
When connected as root, it worked!

```
MariaDB [pktest]> select user();
+----------------+
| user()         |
+----------------+
| root@localhost |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [pktest]> set global use_stat_tables='preferably';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [pktest]> show variables like 'use_stat_tables';
+-----------------+------------+
| Variable_name   | Value      |
+-----------------+------------+
| use_stat_tables | PREFERABLY |
+-----------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Question is, how do I grant privileges to a mariadb user so that the user is able to issue the SET GLOBAL ... command with success?